# CRUD Pattern with API in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a REST API running on the server to create the object. In case there are any validation errors, the API returns 422 with error messages in the response. Simple.

**What I am trying to do**

Show a form to the user to fill in. When the user submits the form, show the loading indicator till the response comes back from the server.

In case the server responds success, then show the details of the object created on the server (basically an ID is now assigned). On back button, the form should not be shown but the widget from where the Form was launched should be shown.

In case the server responds with an error, then show a message and give the user a way to go back to the form to resubmit the form with changes. Ideally, it would be great if the form could be displayed automatically with a snackbar showing the error (or like a web form - errors on top of the form)

Constraint - I would like to avoid having to recreate the Form widget and re-use the one in the stack in case of API error.

**Current Implementation**

I have implemented a widget with a Form widget in flutter. On submit, When the form is valid, I save the form into a local model object. And then post the JSON representation of that object to the server using a service object.

The service object returns a Future of that model object which I use to create the next widget (view model details) and push into the Navigator stack. This widget, uses a FutureBuilder with this future that it receives in the constructor.

In case the FutureBuilder receives an error, I display a message with the button, where I pop the stack from the Navigator and go back to the Form view on click.

If there is no error, then this view displays the object details. But the back arrow in the app bar goes back to the previous Form widget.

**Here the problems start:**

If I use pushReplacement on the Navigator when loading the view that has the Future, then I can't just pop to come back to the Form on error. If I don't, then I come back to the Form even on success.

At present the only way seems to be to handle the Future also in the widget that has the Form and go to the detail widget only if the Future succeeds.But this does not seem a clean way with the Form widget doing too many things.

Is there a better alternative or pattern to achieve this so that I can pop the Form view in case the Future is successful?